# How can I check version of .NET Core of published, self-contained app?

Tags: c#, .net-core

Let's say that I published app 1 month ago with

`dotnet publish --configuration Release -r linux-x64`

how can I check what version of .NET Core (or actually ASP.NET Core Runtime? because that's ASP.NET Core app) is there?

Comment: If you published it as self-contained there should be a `netstandard.dll` in the publish folder. That has the Procuct version of the .NET runtime used by the application.

Comment: @fredrik For some reason all properties in "details" tab of `netstandard.dll` are empty - except `Modification Date` and `Type`

Comment: Do you still have the `<app>.runtimeconfig.json` file in the publish folder?

Comment: Yes, `{"runtimeOptions": {"tfm": "netcoreapp2.1","configProperties": {"System.GC.Server": true}}}`

Comment: There you have it - .net core 2.1

Comment: @fredrik but what about exact version like `2.1.802` `2.1.803`

Comment: Unless you can find some dll that still has it's version information intact and present, you won't find that.

Comment: Why do you need to know this?

Comment: I was curious whether I need to upgrade app due to .net core patches (some arent critical)

Comment: FWIW [this is "fixed"](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-core-3-0#improved-net-core-version-apis), in a manner of sorts, from 3.0 onwards, which has `Environment.Version` and `RuntimeInformation` return something more meaningful. For earlier versions you're still confined to inspecting files.

Comment: I am looking for this to be able to reproduce the build deterministically. Did you find a solution for that? thx

Comment: @DavidMolnar I don't remember how it ended :(

Comment: We ended up with this https://github.com/zkSNACKs/WalletWasabi/issues/6315#issuecomment-962086426